# File that autoruns itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell, autorun

The same way it’s possible to write [a file that autoextracts itself](http://blog.mc-thias.org/?title=auto_extract_tar_file&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1), I’m looking for a way to autorun a program within a script (or whatever it needs). I want the program part of the script, because I just want one file. It’s actually a challenge: I have a xz compressed program, and I wanna be able to run it without any intervention of the xz program by the user (just a ./theprogram).

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean autorun? Can you just put a call to the program in the script, what's wrong with that?

Comment: I want the program part of the script, because I just want one file. It’s actually a challenge: I have a xz compressed program, and I wanna be able to run it without any intervention of the xz program by the user (just a `./theprogram`).

Comment: If you mean can you create an archive that extracts itself and executes something from the contents, yes, of course. The script that does the extraction kicks off the embedded executable once it has been extracted: `exec yourexecutable <arguments>` (exec will replace the current process - the extracting script - with the executable).

Comment: The `autorun` tag (on your question) means: "The system used to provide automatic launch options when removable media is loaded on *Windows* computers", which is not the same as you are asking.  Sounds to me like a security nightmare.

Comment: Take a look at the autoextractor that's used by the Oracle Java installers. (At least they used to use a scheme like this, hopefully they still do so you can look at it.) Basically it wraps a binary in a shell script.

Comment: Kinda like a shar archive (google it) which runs a program after extracting it? Or like python's __main__.py?

Answer (score 0):

Autorun after doing what? Login? Call it in `~/.bashrc`. During boot? Write an appropriate `/etc/init.d/yourprog` and link it to the desired runlevel. Selfextract? Make it a shell archive (shar file). See the `shar` utility, http://linux.die.net/man/1/shar

Comment: see the comment above, I explained all. I’m going to modify the post, it’s not as clear as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I was just thinking... Something like this would not work?
(I am assuming it is a script...)

```
#!/bin/bash

cat << 'EOF' > yourfile
yourscript
EOF

chmod +x yourfile

./yourfile
```

Still, it's pretty hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do... it seems to me that the "autorun" is pretty similar to a "call the program from within the script"..

Comment: Java installers used to follow this path, you'd get a big shell script with an encoded executable embedded into the script that was decoded and run.

Answer (score 0):

I had written a script for this. This should help:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
payload=$(cat $0 | grep --binary-files=text -n ^PAYLOAD: | cut -d: -f1 )
filaname=`head $0 -n $payload | tail -n 1 | cut -d: -f2-`
tail -n +$(( $payload + 1 )) $0 > /tmp/$filaname
set +e
#Do whatever with the payload
exit 0
#Command to add payload:
#read x; ls $x && ( cp 'binary_script.sh' ${x}_binary_script.sh; echo $x >>  ${x}_binary_script.sh; cat $x >> ${x}_binary_script.sh  )
#Note: Strictly NO any character after "PAYLOAD:", not even newline...
PAYLOAD:
```

---

Sample usage:
Suppose `myNestedScript.sh` contains below data:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello world
```

Then run

```
x=myNestedScript.sh; ls $x && ( cp 'binary_script.sh' ${x}_binary_script.sh; echo $x >>  ${x}_binary_script.sh; cat $x >> ${x}_binary_script.sh  )
```

It will generate below file, which you can directly execute. Upon executing below file, it will extract `myNestedScript.sh` to `/tmp` & run that script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
payload=$(cat $0 | grep --binary-files=text -n ^PAYLOAD: | cut -d: -f1 )
filaname=`head $0 -n $payload | tail -n 1 | cut -d: -f2-`
tail -n +$(( $payload + 1 )) $0 > /tmp/$filaname
set +e
chmod 755 /tmp/$filaname
/tmp/$filaname
exit 0
PAYLOAD:myNestedScript.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo hello world
```